# How to get an Id from <select> in React?

Tags: reactjs, select, react-hooks

I have a country dropdown. When the user select any country, its id sent to the database instead of country name. How can I get the id of a selected option?

```
function RegisterPlayer() {
  const handleSubmit = (values, { setFieldError }) => {
    const RegisterAsPlayerForm = {
      full_name: values.fullname,
      display_name: values.displayname,
      nick_name: values.nickname,
      dob: values.dob,
      gender: values.gender,
      country: values.country,
      birth_city: values.city,
      address: values.address,
      phone: values.phone,
      sport_id: values.sport,
      speciality_id: values.speciality,
      user_id: values.user_id,
      file: values.profilephoto,
      coverPhoto: values.coverPhoto,
    };
    let access_token = "fj7VfkpK8Yo4gZwGf4crRPIA5vHj1xw_";

    axios

      .post(
        `http://192.168.18.8/goc-backend/api/web/index.php/v1/player/registerplayer`,
        { RegisterAsPlayerForm },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
```

Here is select option code:

```
<select
 className="inputBox"
 type="option" name="country" onChange={handleChange}
 onBlur={handleBlur} value={values.country} id="country" >
   <option value=""> Country </option>
     {countriesname.map((getcountry) => (
      <option>{getcountry.name} </option> ))}
              </select>
              <p className="req-errors">
                {touched.country && errors.country} </p>
```

Comment: On select pass id rather than its name

Answer (score 1):

When you render the options give the required id to the value field of that option

```
<option value={getcountry.id}>{getcountry.name} </option>
```

and in your onChange function of the select component, you can get the value using,

```
e.target.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Give you options values.  Presumably:

```
<option value={getcountry.id}>{getcountry.name}</option>
```

Or however `getcountry` stores the value you're looking for.  HTML `<option>` elements have a `value` attribute to store their respective values.

Answer (score 0):

add your option as so

```
<select
 onChange={handleChangeCountry}
  value={countrySelected} >
 {countriesname.map((getcountry) => (
    <option value=getcountry.id>{getcountry.name}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

and in your handleChangeCountry

```
const handleChangeCountry = (e) => {
setCountrySelected( e.target.value );
};
```

Comment: I have almost 300 countries in my json file from that files all countries are coming. From your code you are trying to add countries one by one here

Comment: @MuhammadSaadArshad I edit it and add a map it was to show you how